# Организация запуска программы из командной строки

Tags: c#, cmd

Как правильно организовать запуск приложения из командной строки?
Допустим мы имеем приложение ZipApp, которое использует параметры run, name1 и name2. 
Хочется иметь возможность запуска программы из командной строки в двух вариантах:

"C:/Program/ZipApp zipping file1 archive1"
или
"C:/Program/ZipApp unzipping arhive1 file1"

Вот набросок кода, который не работает:

```
void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        if (args[0] != null && args[1] !=null & args[2] != null)
        {
            string run = args[0];
            string name1 = args[1];
            string name2 = args[2];
            switch (run)
            {
                case "zipping":
                    string ZipFileName = name1;
                    string ZipArchName = name2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Создаём архив из файла {0} в архив {1}", ZipFileName,ZipArchName);
                    Zipping(ZipFileName, ZipArchName);
                    break;
                case "unzipping":
                    string UnZipArchName = name1;
                    string UnZipFileName = name2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Разархивируем архив {0} в файл {1}",UnZipArchName,UnZipFileName);
                    Unzipping(UnZipArchName, UnZipFileName);
                    break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Параметры запуска не указаны или указаны не верно");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

беда в том, что при попытке запустить приложение из VS, компилятор ругается:

```
Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for entry point
```

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: Добавьте static перед void Main(string[] args).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Comment: То есть после этого программа теоретиччески должна запскаться из командеой строки? а нельзя проверить из VS& ибо при запуске в VS просто чёрное окно

Comment: @АнтонЛихацкий, про static сказали. про запуск из студии, надо в свойствах проекта на вкладке "Запуск", добавить параметры командной строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно заметил @Umed, для указания параметров запуска из под VS, в свойствах проекта это можно сделать здесь

[image: пример указания аргументов запуска программы]

Программу следует разбивать на методы, по принципу: одна задача - один метод. Так проще писать и тестировать, находить и исправлять ошибки.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //работаем, если есть необходимое кол-во аргументов
        if (args.Length == 3)
        {
            SelectAndRunJob(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Параметры запуска указаны не верно");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void SelectAndRunJob(string typeJob, string fileInput, string fileOutput)
    {
        switch (typeJob)
        {
            case "zipping":
                MakeZip(fileInput, fileOutput);
                break;
            case "unzipping":
                MakeUnzip(fileInput, fileOutput);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Первый аргумент указан вами не верно.");
                Console.WriteLine("Следует указать zipping или unzipping");
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void MakeZip(string fileInput, string fileOutput)
    {
        //прежде чем что-либо делать
        //проверим существование входного файла
        if (!File.Exists(fileInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Архивируемый файл указан не верно.");
            return;
        }

        //далее остальное...
    }

    private static void MakeUnzip(string fileInput, string fileOutput)
    {
        //прежде чем что-либо делать
        //проверим существование входного файла
        if (!File.Exists(fileInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Архивный файл указан не верно.");
            return;
        }

        //далее остальное...
    }
```

Теперь вы сможете отдельно запускать и проверять работу определения аргументов и архивирования/разархивир.

Comment: А как проверить в методе MakeUnzip, является ли fileInput архивом?

Comment: @АнтонЛихацкий а какой у вас архиватор? Zip или другой?

Comment: @АнтонЛихацкий с другой стороны, а зачем проверять? Нужно попытку разархивации обернуть в `try/catch` и в случае ошибки, сообщать пользователю, что формат файла неверный или файл поврежден.

Comment: сделал вот так: try{то и то}catch(InvalidDataException){Console.WriteLine("возможно файл ниразу не архив")}  Так допустимо? )

Comment: @АнтонЛихацкий ну, да, только фраза: "возможно файл ниразу не архив" годится, если вы пишите программу для себя или друзей.